# Spring Boot не видит статик файлы (css, js)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Структура файлов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MediaPlatform</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-boot.version>2.6.2</spring-boot.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.6.3.Final</hibernate.version>
        <postgresql.version>42.3.1</postgresql.version>
        <sqlite-dialect.version>0.1.2</sqlite-dialect.version>
        <validation-api.version>2.0.1.Final</validation-api.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zsoltfabok</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

в шаблоне вызов стиля:
`<link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" />`
Пробовал так же:
`<link href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" />`

Результат один и тот же при открытии http://localhost:8082/css/bootstrap.min.css

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Error 404</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Page not found</h1>
<p>The requested page is not available.</p>
<p><a href="/">Вернуться на главную</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

MvcConfig:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/img/");
    }

}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, куда копать?

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил самостоятельно путем создания фойлового контроллера

```
@GetMapping("/static/{folder}/{fileName:.+}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getStaticFile(@PathVariable String folder, @PathVariable String fileName) {
    Resource file = new ClassPathResource("static/" + folder + "/" + fileName);
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"")
            .body(file);
}
```